# Post full address to the jsonplaceholder using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

- I have spent my whole day to solve that problem but no get the solution so  i need help if any know the solution
- I sent data to the server and get response of users using jsonplaceholder, but whenever i insert the address means full address i was in trouble i don't know how to fetch full address through redux
- I get the street in response but never get the value, Here i only try to fetch street but simillar problem also happen with city,suite etc..
- I share some screenshots hope you all understand and help me!
  [When I enter the data][1]

[When click on Add Button Address is not shown][2]

- In console screenshots

[here in action payload i didn't get the value][3]

[in networktab post request called but address object in street value also never fetch][4]

- Here is my code

```
TableList.js

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { fetchUserList, deletePost, addPost } from '../actions/listActions';
import { get } from 'lodash';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
//import AddressItem from './AddressItem';
//import AddressInput from './AddressInput';


class TableList extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {

          name: '',
          email: '',
          phone: '',
          website: '',
          //  street:''
          address: {
              street: '',
               // suite: '',
               // city: '',
                //zipcode: ''
          }
      }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.props.loadTableList();

  }





 /* handleChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      })
  }*/

  nameChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
          name: e.target.value
      })
  }

  emailChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
          email: e.target.value
      })
  }

  phoneChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
          phone: e.target.value
      })
  }

  websiteChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
          website: e.target.value
      })
  }

  streetChange = (e) => {
  
    //  const { address } = this.state
     
      this.setState({
  
          //[address.street]: e.target.value,
          street: e.target.value,
        //  street: address.street
         
         // street: e.target.value
      
      })
    //  console.log(this.state.address.street)
  
  }


  handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
      const { name, email, phone, website, address} = this.state
      e.preventDefault();
     //debugger
      //console.log(this.state.address.street)
      this.props.addNewpost(name, email, phone, website, address);
      //console.log(address)
      // e.target.name.value = "";
      // e.target.email.value = "";
      // e.target.phone.value = "";
      // e.target.website.value = "";
      //  e.target.street.value = ""
  };



  render() {
      const { tableList } = this.props;

      return (
          <>
              <div style={{ margin: 110 }}>
                  <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
                      <h3>Add User</h3>
                      <input placeholder="Name" name="name" onChange={this.nameChange} />
                      <input placeholder="Email" name="email" onChange={this.emailChange} />
                      <input placeholder="Phone no" name="phone" onChange={this.phoneChange} />
                      <input placeholder="Website" name="website" onChange={this.websiteChange} />
                      <input placeholder="Street" name='street' onChange={this.streetChange} />

                    

                      <button onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>ADD</button>


                  </form>

                  <Table striped bordered hover>
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>id</th>
                              <th>Name</th>
                              <th>Email</th>
                              <th>Address</th>
                              <th>Phone No</th>
                              <th>Website</th>


                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          {tableList.map((user) => {
                              return <tr key={user.name}>
                                  <td>{user.id}</td>
                                  <td>{user.name}</td>
                                  <td>{user.email}</td>
                                  <td>{user.address.street}</td>
                                  <td>{user.phone}</td>
                                  <Link to='/'>{user.website}</Link>


                                  <td>

                                      <button onClick={() => this.props.deletePosts(user.id)}>Delete</button>



                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                      <button>Edit</button>
                                  </td>



                              </tr>

                          })}

                      </tbody>
                  </Table>


              </div>
          </>
      )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      tableList: get(state, ['listReducer', 'posts'], [])
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      loadTableList: () => dispatch(fetchUserList()),
      deletePosts: (id) => dispatch(deletePost(id)),
      
      addNewpost: (name, email, phone, website, address) => dispatch(addPost(name, email, phone, website, address))
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TableList)



**listAction.js**


export const addPost = (name, email, phone, website, address) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
      
      axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', { name, email, phone, website, address })
          // return userService.postUsers({name,email})

          .then(response => {
              dispatch({
                  type: actionTypes.ADD_POST,
                  payload: response.data
              })
          
              console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);

          })
  }
} 


 **tablelistReducer.js**

     
      case actionTypes.ADD_POST:
          console.log(action.payload)
        //  const newPost = state.posts.concat(action.payload)
        
          return{
              ...state,
            posts : [...state.posts,action.payload]
             //posts: newPost
          }
      
      default:
          return state
    
    


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehw9C.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFjzW.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7X2v.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek3NE.jpg
```

Comment: Your links/images are missing.

Comment: lastly of the code available..!